# Executing bash script from Qt which executes script from Octave in background

Tags: bash, qt, raspbian

I tried to make an gui app which as I mentioned in title executes scripts in maybe not conventional way but i dont have any other idea, it works in ubuntu, but i need the same in raspberry. The main problem which i have is that in raspberry the same script didn't works, Qt(button click) executes script in bash which executes script in octave using command `octave --eval nameofscript.m` In ubuntu this works, in raspbian stretch not. I tried this script in bash in raspberry without using qt and it works. This is my code which works in ubuntu:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

 QFile file ("/home/reg-ubu/build-testowy-Desktop-Debug/dane.txt");
    QProcess process;

file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

 process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "-c" << "bash skrypt.sh");
file.close();

}
```

The same i use in raspbian. What i noticed is that when i write the same code in raspbian Qt it says that the skrypt.sh not exist although it is in the same directory as other files of project. Even if i wrote exactly the same path to the skrypt.sh it says then that my script from octave is undefined in `octave --eval nameofscript`. Even when i tried add exactly the same path in this place it will run without problems but i can't see new data in the file. Script from octave is very simple:

```
s =55
plik = fopen('dane.txt','w');
fprintf(plik,'%d\n',s);
fclose(plik);
```

It is only for testing if its working.
To sum up. It should work in this way:
Qt application button click -> runs bash script which runs octave script which send data into dane.txt I tried other ways of executing script in this way, but nothing works than this what i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small test on my Debian Stretch laptop and your script works. I had to add some adjustments to it to make Octave stop. Make sure that the script is executable with `chmod +x script.sh` and you call the script as `./script.sh`. The latter is most certainly your problem.

Try the following code if you're in doubt, I've made you the tiniest program :p

**script.sh**

```matlab
#! /usr/bin/octave
s = 55
plik = fopen('dane.txt','w');
fprintf(plik,'%d\n',s);
fclose(plik);
exit
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QStringList>
#include <iostream>

const char * my_script = "./script.sh";
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        QSize size(80, 25);

        QHBoxLayout layout;
        QWidget window;
        layout.addWidget(&window);

        window.setMinimumSize(size);
        window.setMaximumSize(size);

        QPushButton start;
        start.setText("RUN");
        start.setParent(&window);

        start.connect(&start, &QPushButton::clicked, [] {
                std::cout << "Start process" << std::endl;
                QProcess proc;
                proc.startDetached("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "-c" << my_script);
                proc.waitForReadyRead(-1);
                proc.close();
        });

        window.show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

**proc.pro**

```
QT += core gui widgets
#QT += multimedia

CONFIG += c++17

TARGET = proc
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -g -std=gnu++1z
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lcurl

SOURCES += main.cpp
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
FORMS +=
```